# Determine the namespace of a C# file

Tags: c#, namespaces

How can I determine the namespace of a C# class if it is not defined in the file.

For example, from a class like this:

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Something
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff

    }
        ....
}
```

The class is part of a project in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no namespace is declared in the file, the source is in the "global" namespace. There's no namespace defaulting in C# as there is in VB.

All "real" code really *should* be in a namespace though, for sanity. (I write toy, throwaway code for Stack Overflow questions and blog posts in the global namespace, but nothing I'd want to keep.)

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you explicitly declare a namespace in a C# source file, the compiler adds a default namespace. This unnamed namespace, sometimes referred to as the global namespace, is present in every file. Any identifier in the global namespace is available for use in a named namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit this code, then it's preferable to define a namespace. Without any namespace, you class will be defined at the root level, just next to System / Microsoft etc... Follow the [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229026.aspx) :

> As with other naming guidelines, the goal when naming namespaces is
>   creating sufficient clarity for the programmer using the framework to
>   immediately know what the content of the namespace is likely to be.
>   The following template specifies the general rule for naming
>   namespaces:
>
> < Company>.(< Product>|< Technology>)[.< Feature>][.< Subnamespace>]